# How should I divide up my cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Currently I'm deploying my whole express app as one cloud function on Firebase. Something like this:

```
// index.js
import * as express from "express";
import api1 from "./controllers/api1";
import api2 from "./controllers/api2";

const app = express();
app.use("/api1", api1controller);
app.use("/api2", api2controller);
export const app= functions.https.onRequest(app);

// controllers/api1.js
import * as express from "express";
const router = express.Router();
router.get(...)
router.post(...)
export default router;
```

It's very convenient especially if you want to move your existing express app to cloud function. However I'm thinking about breaking it down and deploy each controller as their own function instead. Something like this

```
// index.js
import * as express from "express";
import api1 from "./controllers/api1";
import api2 from "./controllers/api2";

const app1 = express();
app1.use("/", api1controller);

const app2 = express();
app2.use("/", api2controller);

export const app1= functions.https.onRequest(app1);
export const app2= functions.https.onRequest(app2);
```

At the very least, this improves transparency, when I go to firebase console, I can see that I have 2 controllers, how much activity is going on in each one, and check their separate logs.

Is there any performance or cost issue that I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no significant performance concerns here.

Comment: I see. However there's a discussion [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/170#issuecomment-323375462) also about splitting cloud functions into several files, and this guy proposed to only import the required function at run-time, which may improve performance. Can I ask your opinion on  this?

Comment: For the code you've shown here, there are no performance concerns.  That other issue is dealing with something more specific.